# Monero wallet-rpc keeps saying set max-reorg-depth N no matter what i do

Tags: monero

No matter what I do, my monero-wallet-rpc keeps saying:

```
2021-06-09 15:58:56.402 E reorg_depth > m_max_reorg_depth. THROW EXCEPTION: error::reorg_depth_error
```

And:

```
2021-06-09 15:58:56.430 E Exception at while refreshing, what=reorg exceeds maxi                     mum allowed depth, use 'set max-reorg-depth N' to allow it, reorg depth: 744
```

For the past few days i'v been searching around and no info in regards to this was found. I am trying to run a full monero node with monerod as daemon and wallet-rpc.

This is how I am starting both monerod and wallet-rpc:

```
monerod --config-file /root/.bitmonero/monerod.conf --confirm-external-bind

monero-wallet-rpc --rpc-bind-ip EXTERNAL-IP --rpc-bind-port 18082 --log-level 2 --wallet-file /root/.bitmonero/testwallet --confirm-external-bind --daemon-address EXTERNAL-IP:18081 --daemon-login user:pass --password WALLET-PASSWORD
```

My monerod.conf:

```
data-dir=/root/.bitmonero
log-file=/root/.bitmonero/monero.log
log-level=0
rpc-bind-ip=PUBLIC-IP
rpc-bind-port=18081
rpc-login=user:pass
```

This is how i created the wallet:

```
monero-wallet-cli --trusted-daemon --daemon-address PUBLIC-IP:18081 --daemon-login user:pass
```

Inserted wallet name, password,  didn't set backround mining, refresh done, no errors happened. I hit exit and start the wallet-rpc, then I again get the same error. I try to set max-reorg-depth 744 in the wallet-cli and start the wallet-rpc again ,same error. No matter what I do, same error occurs. Monero doesn't offer any documentation on "set max-reorg-depth N", that's the sad part.

Tried creating multiple different wallets, same error happens on each single one.

Yes, my daemon is fully syncronized, even restarted it couple of times to make sure everything is fine.

If anyone can lighten my day and explain what exactly am I doing wrong ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Problem fixed, all you have to do is open your monero-wallet-cli, load your master wallet and execute the fallowing command: set max-reorg-depth 2378751 ( current number of blocks )